# MTB shifts into spokes

Tags: mountain-bike, shifting

When you shift into the lowest gear at the back it seems to shift but I noticed you can press the shifter one more time which makes the jockey wheel go beyond the back of the cassette.

What is the cause of this? I'm fairly sure I didn't mess with the limit screws on this MTB since its my newest bike and was working nicely.

Comment: If everything is "off by one," that would explain it. Can you shift into the highest gear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rear derailleur got caught in the spokes, what could be a root cause](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62847/rear-derailleur-got-caught-in-the-spokes-what-could-be-a-root-cause) - And lots of other questions with useful answers, please use search if this one does not answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your low-limit screw on the derailleur is allowing the cage and jockey wheels to move too far toward the centerline of the bike, and colliding with the spokes.

This is bad, because if they hook then your forward momentum can pull the derailleur around in a circle with the wheel, causing significant expensive damage to any of the the derailleur, hanger, frame, wheel, chain, hub and spokes.  Plus it leaves the bike unrideable leaving you with a walk home.

The fix is to use a screwdriver to turn the LO limit screw on the rear mech.  This stops the parallelogram moving the lower parts over too far.

Downside, is that this might mess with the rest of your shifting - it may have been off-by-one the whole time.  Test if you can get the chain to the smallest cog as well.

Another remote possibility is to count the number of Clicks your shifter has.  It should be ONE under the count of cogs in your rear cassette.  If you have an 8 speed cassette and 8 clicks, then you have a 9 speed shifter and a "ghost" position.